# Error while Refreshing Excel data using connection with SharePoint Online List

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, excel-services, list-view-threshold, odata

We have created a SharePoint list with 50000+ items in it which has different views.

We exported the same SharePoint list using `Export to Excel` functionality.

After that we created a dashboard on SharePoint and connected that `Excel dashboard to SharePoint List` using `OData Data Feed` of Excel Connection.

But whenever we are trying to Refresh the excel dashboard data, it is showing **You do not have permission to view entire list because it is larger than the list view threshold enforced by the administrator**.

Kindly suggest a suitable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue occurs because SharePoint Online uses the Large List Resource Throttling feature. By default, the list view threshold is configured at 5,000 items. When the defined item limit in a list is exceeded, the error message will be displayed. For SharePoint Online, this limit can't be changed.

Export a large list to an Excel will let you work with large list without blocking. But if you connect the table to the list (from OData Data Feed) using the listdata web service, it will throw threshold error if the list has more than at 5,000 items.

[Information about how to manage large lists/libraries in SPO](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-SharePoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59).